# Добавить значение в массив laravel

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Как добавить все значения в массив?

Следующий код добавляет только один элемент:

```
$array= [];
foreach ($request->file('picture') as $item)
{
    $fl= $item->getClientOriginalName();
    $array = array_add($array, '', $fl);
    $item->move($path, $fl);
}

return print_r($array);
```

Хотя там всего должно быть пять элементов.

Comment: `$array` => `$array[]  = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заносить значения в массив через метод [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php):

> `array_push` — добавляет один или несколько элементов в конец массива

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации Laravel, метод [`array_add`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-add) добавляет пару ключ-значение в массив, если данный ключ еще не существует в массиве. Согласно вашему коду:

```
array_add($array, '', $fl);
```

Вы всегда добавляете один и тот же ключ, поэтому будет добавлен лишь первый элемент, даже если итераций в вашем цикле `foreach` было больше чем одна (пять к примеру). Чтобы добавить все значения в массив, необходимо указывать уникальные ключи каждому добавляемому элементу, это второй параметр в методе [`array_add`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-add).